# How do you translate "Executive Director"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here are some possible answer I found (and their sources):

- *administra direktoro* (Wimedia Apertium instance, one might also infer *administrestro* fron this)
- *manaĝerestro* (infered from majstro.com propositions)
- *plenuma direktoro* (google translate)

Also, feel free to provide any trustable reference regarding job/position names in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%88efa_afergvida_oficisto

- CEO = ĉefa afergvida oficisto
- General Director =  ĝenerala direktoro

> How do you translate “*Executive Director*”?

Executive director = afergvida direktoro

Comment: Do, aferestro estus egale ebla, ĉu ne? Direktoro estas speco de estro, kaj la PIVa difino de "estri" donas "gvidi" kiel alirigardinda.

Comment: Aferestro  = estro de aferoj